# Moving custom fields from quote to project XTRF Client Portal API

Tags: xtrf

I have a problem with moving Custom Fields from quote to project.
Quotes are created via Client Portal API and as far as I know theses quotes are classic ones. When I create project from classic quote, project doesn't populate custom fields.

I tried to update project manually with quote's custom fields.
Everything I have is classic quote with numeric id. I extracted idNumber from quote, and searched for project using with method https://prisma.s.xtrf.us/customer-api/doc/pages/projects.html#GET_/projects and adding `?search=quoteIdNumber`.
Then I received project created from quote.

I tried to update project's customFields manually from quote's customFields, but I didn't succeed. I extracted projectId from received project and tried this method [https://prisma.s.xtrf.us/api/doc/users/pages/v1-projects.html#PUT_/projects/{projectId}/customFields](https://prisma.s.xtrf.us/api/doc/users/pages/v1-projects.html#PUT_/projects/%7BprojectId%7D/customFields) to update project's custom fields. I received error that I am trying to update Smart Project and I should use newer API, but V2 API for Smart Projects requires different project Id than I received. I received project id like this `576`, but updating smart project requires id like this `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP`.

Is there a way to move custom fields from classic quote created via Client Portal API to new smart project created from that quote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using different custom field scope?
What I mean is a scope where custom field is shared between quote and project.
See picture
[image: Choosing scope for custom field - Quote + Project should do the trick]

Comment: Thank you that was helpful and worked as expected and custom fields are available for quotes. But what about creating new quotes with values for these custom fields? I am trying to create new quote with values for custom fields created via XTRF Portal, but each time I use this request https://xtrf.target-languages.com/customer-api/doc/pages/quotes.html#POST_/quotes to create new quote I receive 500 Internal error when custom fields are in request.

Comment: Can you tell me what you get in the logs? You may get a 500 when providing wrong keys.